# How does the weight work in gglasso R package

Tags: feature-selection, lasso

I am using `gglasso` package to perform regularized weighted least square for grouped variables. But I was confused with their `weight` argument.

[In their tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gglasso/vignettes/Introduction_to_gglasso_package.html)

```
# generate weight matrix
times <- seq_along(bardet$y)
rho <- 0.5
sigma <- 1
H <- abs(outer(times, times, "-"))
V <- sigma * rho^H
p <- nrow(V)
V[cbind(1:p, 1:p)] <- V[cbind(1:p, 1:p)] * sigma

# reduce eps to speed up convergence for vignette build
fit_wls <- gglasso(x = bardet$x, y = bardet$y, group = group1, loss = "wls", 
                   weight = V, eps = 1e-4)

plot(fit_wls)
```

While in page 8 of [their paper](http://users.stat.umn.edu/%7Ezouxx019/Papers/gglasso-paper.pdf), they use $\tau_i$ to denote the weight. It seems to be a $n \times 1$ vector since each observation has only one weight. Why they construct a weight  $n \times n$ matrix like that in tutorial?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.